# Finding a grammar for this language

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I need to find a context free grammar for the following language:

> L= { w from { a,b,c,d }* : #a+2#b=2#c+#d }

Here is my attempt, but I doubt it is correct:

```
S -> aSd|dSa|BSC|CSB|abSdc|baScd|dcSab|cdSba|SS|λ
B -> c|dd
C -> b|aa
```

Comment: Why is there a lambda in your grammar? Is that the same as an ε-production (empty-string)?

Comment: @DaoWen Yes λ is same as ε

Comment: I'm sure you can construct a CFG for _a_ language that has that property—but I'm pretty sure it's impossible to generate that exact language with a CFG. For example, how can you generate `aacbdd`?

Comment: @DaoWen I am confused, do you mean the language is not context free, or do you mean my CFG isn't right for the language? For 'aacbdd' using the grammar I have there I think I can do S=>aSd=>aaSdd=>aaBSCdd=>aacSbdd=>aacbdd

Comment: I meant that I don't think the language is context free. Using your current grammar you can also generate S -> aSd -> ad, which isn't supposed to be in the language. You have to count too many things in this language for it to be context-free. There's no way you can maintain the #a+2#b=2#c+#d relationship with just the stack of a [PDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#PDA_and_Context-free_Languages).

Comment: @DaoWen Why 'ad' is in the language for sure. I hope the notation isn't confusing, by #a I mean number of a's in the word and so on. I wasn't able to apply the pumping lemma to show it isn't context free, which would be a satisfying answer.

Comment: You're right, I was confused. In that case, you should also be able to generate `cb` and `aaccaa`.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a PDA that recognizes the language like this:

- The characters `a` and `b` in the input correspond to `a` on the stack.
- The characters `c` and `d` correspond to `c` on the stack.
- If the stack is empty or the top is `a`, and `a` is on the input, consume it and push `a` to the stack.
- If the stack is empty or the top is `a`, and `b` is on the input, consume it and push `aa` to the stack.
- If the stack is empty or the top is `c`, and `c` is on the input, consume it and push `cc` to the stack.
- If the stack is empty or the top is `c`, and `d` is on the input, consume it and push `c` to the stack.
- If the stack top is `c` and `a` is on the input, consume `a` and pop the `c`.
- If the stack top is `c` and `b` is on the input, consume `b` and pop the `c`, moving to a special state that either pop another `c` or pushes an `a` if the stack is empty.
- ...
- The accept state is where both the input and stack are empty.

That means you *must* be able to construct a CFG. I think you're on the right track, but this CFG is going to be a pain to write since there are no ordering constraints. This means you'll have a lot of permutations of the same basic rule.